# "Lane User Stack Overflow" debugging CUDA program

Tags: c++, cuda

I am using Totalview to try to debug a CUDA kernel.  I have selected the option to debug memory errors in CUDA, and stop on memory errors on the host.

I am getting a stop in one ofm y kernels on this line:

```
d_test_filt[i*cols+j] = cuCmulf(cuCmulf(d_usKernel[i*cols + j],d_convolver[i*cols + j]),d_rr[i*cols + j]) ;
```

the error in the bar says "Lane User Stack Overflow"

What does this error mean exactly? How do I fix the problem?

In this case, all of those d_ arrays have been allocated on the device. i*cols+j is far less than the size of the arrays (1024 x 1024) where i and j are 311 and 808 respectively

Answer (score 3):

The CUDA-gdb manual says:

> CUDA_EXCEPTION_2 : “Lane User Stack Overflow”
>
> This occurs when a thread exceeds its stack memory limit.

For explanation of what a lane is the CUDA-gdb manual says:

> A device thread belongs to a block, which in turn belongs to a kernel.
>   Thread, block, and kernel are the software coordinates of the focus. A
>   device thread runs on a lane. A lane belongs to a warp, which belongs
>   to an SM, which in turn belongs to a device. Lane, warp, SM, and
>   device are the hardware coordinates of the focus. Software and
>   hardware coordinates can be used interchangeably and simultaneously as
>   long as they remain coherent.

The CUDA-gdb manual has more info about retrieving info from lanes among others. For this error you exceeded the maximum stack memory limit as AJG85 said.

Comment: I suggest you find the cause of the stack overflow, but if it is unavoidable, you can increase the per-thread stack size using [`cudaDeviceSetLimit()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gb8a22e29cc297634b0702db0b69f59e7.html)

Comment: As for finding the cause - I mean, the only thing that can be done is probably removing variable declarations in the kernels, right?

Answer (score 1):

A *stack overflow* can be caused by many factors. Generally it means just what it says. There is a limited amount of memory on the call stack and you have exceeded it. A few common mistakes that can cause this are deep recursion and infinite loops where you have so many calls on the stack you exceed the memory available.

This is different from an *out of range* or *out of bounds* exception where you are trying to access memory beyond what was allocated and available to the object which could be caused by indexing past the end of the array as you described in the question. Not the case here.

I have no idea what a *Lane User* is but I suspect that is terminology related to CUDA that you could probably look up somewhere on the nvidia website. You will need to show more of the surrounding code for a better answer as what you have shown is insufficient to identify what might have caused this error.